# JS Цикл, пока не выполнится условие

Tags: javascript, циклы, условия

Данный ниже код ищет на поисковой странице (запрос ввожу я сам) Ютуба видео по названию канала, затем кликает по нему.
Мне необходимо добавить в код **window.scrollBy(0,5500);**, [это скролл страницы], так, чтобы он выполнялся бесконечно, пока не будет найдено нужное видео с канала - затем уже кликнуть по нему, у меня за клик сейчас отвечает строка **elem.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('a#thumbnail').click();**

```js
(() => {
   const coll = document.querySelectorAll('div#channel-info');
   let elem;
   for (let item of coll) {
      if ( item.innerText == 'НАЗВАНИЕ КАНАЛА' && (elem = item) )
         break;
   };
   if (elem)
      elem.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('a#thumbnail').click();
   else
      alert('Не найдено!');
})();
```

Пробовал вот так (но тут ограниченное кол-во скроллов + по видосу он в итоге не кликает):

```js
(() => {
   const coll = document.querySelectorAll('div#channel-info');
   let elem;
   for (let item of coll) {
      if ( item.innerText == 'НАЗВАНИЕ_КАНАЛА' && (elem = item) )
         break;
   };
   if (elem)
      elem.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('a#thumbnail').click();
   else
      for (let i=1; i<15; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        window.scrollBy(0,5500);
    }, i*1200 );
      }
})();
```

**Буду благодарен за помощь!**

Comment: Добавьте комментарии в код, непонятно какую часть нужно зациклить

Answer (score 0):

Весь код помещаем в функцию и работаем по следующему алгоритму:

1. Ищем кнопку
2. - Нашли - нажимаем
   - Нет - мотаем страницу вниз и запускаем функцию с небольшой задержкой
3. Возвращаемся к пункту 1

```js
const findAndClick = (channelName, delay) => {
  const blocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div#channel-info'));

  let elem = blocks.find((item) => item.innerText.trim().toLowerCase() == channelName.toLowerCase())

  if (elem) {
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('a#thumbnail').click();
  } else {
    window.scrollBy(0, 5500)

    setTimeout(() => {
      findAndClick(channelName, delay)
    }, delay)
  }
}

findAndClick('Название канала', 3000)
```

Comment: Daniil Dubchenko, ваш код выдает следующую ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: blocks.find is not a function at findAndClick (<anonymous>:4:21) at <anonymous>:17:1